# http not working in ionic 2

Tags: http, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using http module in ionic 2 to hit a get request but my webstorm complains that this module is deprecated.I have also used httpModule but it says the same for it.Below is my piece of code:

```
import {Http} from "@angular/http";

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private authService:AuthService,private http:Http) {

  }
```

And below is the error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError[Http]: 
  StaticInjectorError[Http]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!
Error: StaticInjectorError[Http]: 
  StaticInjectorError[Http]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!
```

Comment: which is your angular version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add module in app.module.ts file

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

and pass it to `imports:[]`

```
imports: [
        ...
        HttpModule,
        ...
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **angular version 5** or above, `HttpModule` from `@angular/http` is [**deprecated**](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#deprecated-code).

You need to use `HttpClient` from `@angular/common/http`.

Import `HttpClientModule`.

```
 import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";


 imports: [
    ...
    HttpClientModule,
    ...
],
```

And in your page,

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

//...
constructor(public http: HttpClient){}
```

Check [latest docs](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Comment: I am developing in ionic 2 and hence using angular 2.I got the fix though :) Thanks for the inputs though.

Comment: ok.. will leave the answer in case people upgraded angular :)